# How to create login page that redirects based on usertype

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a php mysql login page which works fine (very basic at present) once the user is verified. After logging in there username and usertype is echoed at the top of the login page.

I am struggling now, to have them directed to different page based on there usertype.

I have added a redirect.php which redirects based on usertyoe.

Here are my files thus far.

```
    //config.php
    <?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    //timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bahrain');

    //database
    define('DBHOST','localhost');
    define('DBUSER','phpmyadmin');
    define('DBPASS','pupitadmin');
    define('DBNAME','user_register');

    // address
    define('DIR','https://mysite/');
    define('SITEEMAIL','myemail@gmail.com');

    try {

        //create PDO connection
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //show error
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        exit;
    }

    //include the user class, pass in the database connection
    include('classes/user.php');
    $user = new User($db);
    ?>



   //index.php

     <?php

    require_once('includes/config.php');


    //process login form if submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if (!isset($_POST['username'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";
        if (!isset($_POST['password'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        if ( $user->isValidUsername($username)){
            if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
                $error[] = 'A password must be entered';
            }
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if($user->login($username,$password)){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        header('Location: redirect.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password.';
    }
}
```

}

```
    $title = 'Login';

    ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
                <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                    <h2>Login</h2>

                    <?php
                    //check for any errors
                    if(isset($error)){
                        foreach($error as $error){
                            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                        }
                    }

                    ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="3">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    //userpage.php
    <?php
    include('password.php');
    class User extends Password{

        private $_db;

        function __construct($db){
            parent::__construct();

            $this->_db = $db;
        }

        private function get_user_hash($username){

            try {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, usertype FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
                $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

                return $stmt->fetch();

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }
        }

        public function isValidUsername($username){
            if (strlen($username) < 3) return false;
            if (strlen($username) > 17) return false;
            if (!ctype_alnum($username)) return false;
            return true;
        }

        public function login($username,$password){
            if (!$this->isValidUsername($username)) return false;
            if (strlen($password) < 3) return false;

            $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

            if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
                $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
                return true;
            }
        }

        public function logout(){
            session_destroy();
        }

        public function is_logged_in(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
                return true;
            }
        }



    //adminpage
    <?php require('includes/config.php'); 

    $title = 'Admin Page';
    ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">

                    <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES); 
                    echo " - ";
                    echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['usertype'], ENT_QUOTES);
                    ?></h1>
                    <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
                    <hr>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


// redirect.php
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 


ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$title = 'Admin Page';
if(isset($_SESSION['usertype'])=== 'user') {
             header('Location: userpage.php');
}
else {


            header('Location: adminpage.php');
            exit;
}

?>
```

```
Now I can start to add better security and vailadation as advised.
```

Comment: You might be getting PHP errors, do you have errors showing? Try this at the top of your php page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Answer (score 0):

You reference $usertype but as far as the code shows it is never defined by that point

```
if ( $usertype == "admin"){

        header("location:adminpage.php");

        } else  if ( $usertype == "user"){

        header("location: userpage.php");

        }
```